# Finding next single instance of class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of div classes ("item") which sit next to each other, and I need to find the next instance of "clear" so I can manipulate an item based on downloadPadderX. I'm using .each() to loop through each instance of "item" and will do the manipulations within that function.

However, I don't seem to be able to return a single instance of the next clear. It just returns an empty array. If I use nextAll, it returns all of the clear's, which isn't very helpful.

**HTML**

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="clear downloadPadder1"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="clear downloadPadder2"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery('.item').each(function(){
    console.log(jQuery(this).next('.clear').attr('class')); // This returns "undefined".
});
```

Basic JSFiddle link if it's helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/lustre/uhmkutqm/

For each instance of "item" I need it to return the next "clear".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)** and **[`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)**. **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** will only select element immediately after the element. **[`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)** will return all elements next to that , then you can pick nearest one using **[`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)**

```
jQuery('.item').each(function(){
    console.log(jQuery(this).nextAll('.clear').first().attr('class')); // This returns "undefined".
});
```

Comment: @Natalie : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`.nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uhmkutqm/1/